# HTTP & RPC at the same time

Tags: http, go, rpc

I am  trying to implement `rpc` and `http` server in my system.
So to listen servers at the same time I have run 2 `goroutines`
Here is a code

```
func main() {
    // Recovering all errors during the process
    defer errorHandler()

    wg.Add(2)

    go RPCConnect()

    fmt.Println("Listening for RPC   127.0.0.1:" + config.rpcPort)

    go HTTPConnect()

    fmt.Println("Listening for HTTP  127.0.0.1:" + config.httpPort)

    wg.Wait()
}


func RPCConnect() {
    err := rpc.Register(pool)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rpc.HandleHTTP()

    listener, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+config.rpcPort)
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    err = http.Serve(listener, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func HTTPConnect() {

    var httpPool HTTPPool

    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/create", httpPool.Create).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/generate", httpPool.Generate).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/list", httpPool.List).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/delete", httpPool.Delete).Methods("POST")

    err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:"+config.httpPort, r)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

I dont know is this a best way or not . Can somebody tell me more simple and flexible method?

I apologize in advance if the question is not relevant

Comment: This is fine, except that the `sync.WaitGroup` is not necessary: `http.Serve`/`http.ListenAndServe` only return on error. Depending on your situation, alternative solutions could be to deploy two processes alongside one another by a) creating two binaries (`cmd/http` and `cmd/rpc`) or b) creating a single binary but use a flag to determine whether it should run in HTTP or RPC "mode".

Comment: @EmilePels thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suggested approach is pretty well.

If you want to use only one port instead of two, there are several third-party tools to do it:

1) https://github.com/soheilhy/cmux

2) https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway